# Where does Pipenv get their CVE data from?

Tags: python, pipenv

I'm looking at `pipenv check` and seems like they pull CVE data from some upstream database somewhere. I'm trying to figure out where it gets this data from so that I can get specific CVE information on specific packages and version instead of my virtualenv packages. i.e. something akin to

```
get_cves('django', '1.8')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipenv appears to [include a patched version](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/tree/master/pipenv/patched/safety) of [the `safety` library](https://pypi.org/project/safety/) directly in its source tree. `safety` [uses its own open-source vulnerability database by default](https://github.com/pyupio/safety-db), though there is also a paid database that you can use if you prefer or if you need a commercial license:

> The database is licensed under [CC BY-NC-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/). This allows you to use the data in any non commercial project as long as you link back to this repo. If you need a license for a commercial project, please contact support@pyup.io.

The commercial license part is quite interesting. Since Pipenv itself is [released under the MIT license](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/blob/master/LICENSE) one would expect to be able to use it commercially. But the `check` subcommand may not be usable under that license due to the terms of the underlying database.

If you're planning to use this stuff commercially you might want to talk to a lawyer first, or simply pay for a database license.